# Why the select_type of query "select xxx in (select xxx)" isn't SUBQUERY?

Tags: mysql

I create tables and insert some data like:

```sql
create table t1(id int(10) auto_increment primary key, content varchar(100) null);
create table t2(id int(10) auto_increment primary key, content varchar(100) null);
insert into t1(content) values(concat('t1_', floor(1+rand()*100)));
insert into t2(content) values(concat('t1_', floor(1+rand()*100)));
```

If I run `explain select * from t1 where id = (select id from t2);` the select_type is `SUBQUERY`
[image: SUBQUERY]

But If I run `explain select * from t1 where id in (select id from t2);` why the select_type is `SIMPLE` not `SUBQUERY`?
[image: SIMPLE]

What's the difference between the two statement?

Comment: Run a show warnings satatement after running the explain to get more insights as to what hapoens under the hood. My guess is that mysql optimiser rewrote the 2nd query as a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/semijoins.html says:

> ```
> SELECT class_num, class_name
>     FROM class
>     WHERE class_num IN
>         (SELECT class_num FROM roster);
> ```
>
> Here, the optimizer can recognize that the IN clause requires the subquery to return only one instance of each class number from the roster table. In this case, **the query can use a semijoin;** that is, an operation that returns only one instance of each row in class that is matched by rows in roster.

(emphasis mine)

Read the manual page I linked to for more explanation.

By the way, if you add more than one row to t2 and the subquery matches more than one row, you get an error. A value in the outer query can't be simultaneously equal to multiple values.

```
mysql> insert into t2 ...

mysql> explain select * from t1 where id = (select id from t2);
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```